# Building a List w/ Weird Structure(?)

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I am having an issue in building a list in R to match the structure of a decoded JSON object.

Consider the following list `tbl`, constructed as follows using `jsonlite::fromJSON()`

```r
tbl <- jsonlite::fromJSON('{"toplevel": [{"midlevel": {"id":"1",
"country":"US"
}},{"midlevel": {"id":"2",
"country":"US"
}},{"midlevel": {"id":"3",
"country":"GB"
}},{"midlevel": {"id":"5",
"country":"FR"
}}]}')

tbl
#> $toplevel
#>   midlevel.id midlevel.country
#> 1           1               US
#> 2           2               US
#> 3           3               GB
#> 4           5               FR

str(tbl)
#> List of 1
#>  $ toplevel:'data.frame':    4 obs. of  1 variable:
#>   ..$ midlevel:'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   .. ..$ id     : chr [1:4] "1" "2" "3" "5"
#>   .. ..$ country: chr [1:4] "US" "US" "GB" "FR"
```

You can see that `tbl$toplevel` is a data frame with 4 rows and 1 column, but that `tbl$toplevel$midlevel` also has 4 rows.

I need to be able to build a list with the same structure, so that it encodes the same when using `jsonlite::toJSON()`, but I'm having some issues.

```r
tbl_attempt <-
  list(
    toplevel = data.frame(
      midlevel = data.frame(
        id = c(1, 2, 3, 5),
        country = c("US", "US", "GB", "FR"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      ), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  )

tbl_attempt
#> $toplevel
#>   midlevel.id midlevel.country
#> 1           1               US
#> 2           2               US
#> 3           3               GB
#> 4           5               FR

str(tbl_attempt)
#> List of 1
#>  $ toplevel:'data.frame':    4 obs. of  2 variables:
#>   ..$ midlevel.id     : num [1:4] 1 2 3 5
#>   ..$ midlevel.country: chr [1:4] "US" "US" "GB" "FR"
```

Per the reprex above, `tbl_attempt` prints exactly the same as `tbl` to the console, but the structure is different. Any ideas how to replicate the structure of `tbl`?

I've considered using `dput()`, but this feels a bit hacky so would rather avoid.

Comment: why do you think using `dput` is hacky ? Infact, I think it is the easiest way to reproduce the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in two steps:

```
tbl2 <- list(
  toplevel = data.frame(
    midlevel = seq_len(4)
  )
)
tbl2$toplevel$midlevel <- data.frame(
  id = c("1", "2", "3", "5"),
  country = c("US", "US", "GB", "FR"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Comment: Works a treat. Thank you!